# how to use a variable outside of an if statement that is already declared inside an if statement

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement

hey guys im just learning C# in school and am having trouble figuring out how i can use a variable outside of an if statement when that variable is already declared inside an if statement..heres what my program looks like........i have to use the "factor" variable outside of the if statemants because it is part of an equation that i need for a school assignment..if i am missing anything or you need more information, plz dont hesitate to tell me

```
 public caloriesCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double kilos;
            double pounds;
            int factor;
            double totalcalories;
            pounds = double.Parse(lbsTxt.Text);
            kilos = pounds * 0.45;
            kilosTxt.Text = kilos.ToString();


            {

                if (maleRadio.Checked && activeRadio.Checked)
                {
                    factor = 15;
                }

                if (femaleRadio.Checked && activeRadio.Checked)
                {
                    factor = 12;
                }

                if (maleRadio.Checked && inactiveRadio.Checked)
                {
                    factor = 13;
                }

                if (femaleRadio.Checked && inactiveRadio.Checked)
                {
                    factor = 10;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove the extra { } before your if and at your last if. C# has blockscope for variables and { } denotes a block therfore `factor` is not defined when you reach your if statement...

Comment: hi i deleted the extra {} and still get a build error when i try to make my formula, which is "totalcalories = factor * kilos;", it has factor underlined and says that use of local variable "factor"

Answer (score 2):

Not clear: But are you saying that this doesn't compile? You need to assign a value (a default) before  going inside the if statement.

```
int factor = 15;
```

Comment: This sounds correct. Even if you know that all four combinations of radiobuttons are covered, the compiler doesn't catch this and should give you a compile error.

Comment: sorry could you please explain that to me in more detail? and no it doesnt compile, and assigning a value, what do you mean?

Comment: variables need to initialised before they can be referenced. Just declaring a variable does not initialise it. you need to assign a value to the variable before you can use it.

Comment: ok but the thing is i need it to have different values depending on certain conditions (which radio buttons are selected)

Comment: You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/4y7h161d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more details. If you had a else statement associated with the if, then you wouldn't have gotten that error

Answer (score 1):

You do need to initialize your variables, but if you want to return a number you need to do it with an int type. Void means return nothing. Try using an int method to do this, and return the variable.

I.E. private int radioChecker()

```
if(this happens) {
factor = 15;
return factor;
}
```

etc etc

then place radioChecker() inside your void and you can have different things happen based on what it returns.